# Catch block doesn't get fired

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got an async call of API where the second .catch block is not being executed.

Fist I defined main API call function in utils file like so:

```
   const getCustomer= (body) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      fetch('/getCustomer', {
        method: 'post',
        body: JSON.stringify(body),
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json"
            Content-type: "application/json"
-       },
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => resolve(json))
      .catch(err => console.log('error happened', err))
    })
  };
```

Later on in my JSX file I call the API by importing the function above.

```
getCustomer(myPayload).then(res => {
 setCustomer(res)
}).catch(err => {
 setShowError(true)
})
```

What I am trying to do is to show the error message with setShowError, but for some reason I can only see the `console.log('error happened', err)` throwing out from utils folder, where I define my fetch function.
Any idea on how I can fix this behavior and execute catch function

Comment: It's not valid JS; won't compile as-is. Please include your actual code.

Comment: somebody already gave me an answer

Comment: Yes, I know. That doesn't mean the code shouldn't be real code.

Comment: My friend, what If I don't want to share my real code?? I just changed namings, thats it.

Comment: ... Posted code should be syntactically correct. This avoids people going down an irrelevant rabbit hole. There's a reason for that--the closer code is to runnable the less people have to think about it. This helps people help you and is a good habit to get in to.

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. [When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: you need to throw error from catch block of fetch method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want both `.catch`es to execute, you'll need to throw inside the first, otherwise the result will be that `getCustomer` will always return a Promise that resolves. You'll also need to use the `reject` parameter to the Promise constructor.

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // ...
    .catch(err => {
        console.log('error happened', err);
        reject(err);
    })
```

and make sure to return the Promise call in your React code:

```
return setCustomer(res);
```

While this is *possible*, usually a better approach, if feasible, is to not catch the error below, and instead let the caller handle it. Also don't use the explicit Promise construction antipattern.

```
   const getCustomer= (body) => {
    return fetch('/getCustomer', {
        method: 'post',
        body: JSON.stringify(body),
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json"
            Content-type: "application/json"
-       },
      })
      .then(response => response.json());
  };
```

is what I'd prefer. Unless you really need the `setCustomer` itself to handle it too, just let the error percolate up to its caller.